# How build wireless-compat-old in-kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi, drivers, wlan

I'm running linux 2.6.24 with custom patches from Freescale, on an embedded board. I want to use a usb wlan modem that uses the Realtek rtl8191su chipset.

Realtek provides a driver out of tree, RTL819xSU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405.zip. I've extracted and built that driver but I get errors about usb read/write timeouts, that I've not been able to diagnose the causes of.

I want to try the in-kernel [rtl8712](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/rtl8712/) usb wlan driver. It was added upstream in 2.6.37. I'd like to avoid updating the whole tree due to all the custom patches applied.

I've found instructions on how to build compat wireless modules [here](http://nilvec.com/how-to-use-the-latest-80211-drivers-and-stack-with-linux.html). But that's for building kernel modules. My board does not use modules - how can I alter my linux 2.6.24 tree to contain the changes brought in by compat-wireless?